# Dropbox API, сгенерировать токен приложения правильно

Tags: dropbox

Хочу использовать Dropbox API для хостинга изображений на сайте. Добавлять их буду только я (через десктопное приложение), а вот "тягать" с него будет JavaScript на сайте, то есть нужен токен, который имеет права только на это.
Для этого, как я понял, нужно зарегистрировать приложение, что я и сделал.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Там же можно сгенерировать, собственно, токен, но предназначен он именно что для закрытых приложений. А на сайте-то он будет виден, к тому же такой токен предусматривает безлимитные права (если не ошибаюсь), и потому любой, кто его увидит, сможет напакастить.

Я плохо разобрался с этим API, но если кто работал, подскажите, если не трудно, как это всё устроено и с того ли вообще конца я начал разбираться в API.